# Django Celery: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm adding `django-celery` to my project, there's currently an issue you'll experience where a first install of this installs an outdated `celery` which you need to update and it has a dependency `django-celery-results` which also has it's expected version for each depending on it's version.
I've ended up with the following versions

```
Name: django-celery-results
Version: 1.0.0

Name: django-celery
Version: 3.3.1

Name: celery
Version: 4.4.0
```

in my app/tasks.py I have the following code

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.conf import settings

@shared_task
def update_extend():
    users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    for user in users:
        ....
```

based on the docs this seems like the next line of code to test

```
(fortnox) sam@sam:/media/veracrypt1/fortnox$ python manage.py celery
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/sam/code/envs/fortnox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "/home/sam/code/envs/fortnox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/sam/code/envs/fortnox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 244, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
File "/home/sam/code/envs/fortnox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 37, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
File "/home/sam/code/envs/fortnox/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/sam/code/envs/fortnox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djcelery/management/commands/celery.py", line 11, in <module>
    class Command(CeleryCommand):
File "/home/sam/code/envs/fortnox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djcelery/management/commands/celery.py", line 16, in Command
    tuple(base.get_options()) +
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

which throws the error shown above.

Answer (score 3):

`django-celery` does not support Django versions higher than Django 1.10.* also does not [support](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/issues/568) celery 4.*.*

From [Celery documentation for Django](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

> Previous versions of Celery required a separate library to work with
>   Django, but since 3.1 this is no longer the case. Django is supported
>   out of the box now so this document only contains a basic way to
>   integrate Celery and Django. You’ll use the same API as non-Django
>   users so you’re recommended to read the First Steps with Celery
>   tutorial first and come back to this tutorial. When you have a working
>   example you can continue to the Next Steps guide.

You can still use `django-celery-results` but withouth needs of djcelery